# Can a Google Apps Script create a Google News Alert?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can Google Apps Script create a Google News Alert? I've not been able to find any script example doing this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

There is no built-in function for this, unfortunately.

You would have to capture the form submission by monitoring the network traffic when you create an alert and then emmulate making the POST request to the correct URL from Apps Script with all the headers/cookies needed to identify yourself.